# Invoke Js function to set Composite Component attribute

Tags: javascript, html, composite-component

I have a composite component, and for setting one of it's attributes I have to call a Js function that makes a calculation. How can I do this?

JS Function

```
function getContWidth() {
             var width = ($("#content_container_wide").css("width"));
             return width;
        };
```

Comp Component

```
<comp:carouselComponent id="carousel" title="Carousel images" 
                        images="#{carouselBean.imageList}"
                        height="170" numToDisplay="3" 
                        width="#{document.write(getContWidth())}" />
```

Comment: I dont think you need `document.write()` in there, or do you? Have you tried `#{getContWidth()}`

Comment: @BatuZet yes, already tried. Got this error; Function ':getContWidth' not found =(